# Eventbrite API refund request returns 403 Error

Tags: php, eventbrite

Can anyone advise how or what I am missing?
The update, create event or ticket, they are all working fine except the refund API.

```
$eventBriteModel = new zerolfc\eventbrite\HttpClient(TOKEN);

$refundItems = [
 ['order_id' => $eventbrite_order_id]
];

$eventBriteModel->post('/refund_requests/', [
 'from_name' => $attendee_name,
 'from_email' => $attendee_email,
 'items' => json_encode($refundItems),
 'message' => $message,
 'reason' => $reason
]);

[status_code] => 403
[error_description] => You do not have permission to access the resource you requested.
[error] => NOT_AUTHORIZED
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you fix it? I am going to contact their support.

Comment: @Alain nope. Their dev contacted me via email, but it was very slow reply and was not going anywhere.

Comment: I have to get this to work for my job, so I will update this answer once I figure it out.

Comment: @Alain Please do :). I wrote a support request in their google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eventbrite-api/SvTiifiNFeI